# Typescript Error TS2339: Property does not exist on type (Angular 12)

Tags: angular, typescript

With the following code I get

> error TS2339: Property 'timestamp' does not exist on type 'LogRepair[]'

In the component html, I am trying to iterate through any array of properties defined in type `LogRepair`:

```
<div>
<div *ngFor = "let repair of repairs" class="repair_list">
    <div class = "RT">{{repairs.name}}</div>
    <div class = "Repair Type">{{repairs.type}}</div>
    <div class = "Gecko Number">{{repairs.phoneID}}</div>
    <div class = "Warranty Sticker">{{repairs.stickerID}}</div>
    <div class = "Description">{{repairs.description}}</div>
    <div class = "Timestamp">{{repairs.timestamp}}</div>
</div>
```

In the component ts, I am importing the `LogRepair` model and declaring a property called `repairs`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LogRepairService } from '../log-repair.service';
import { LogRepair } from '../LogRepair.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-repairs',
  templateUrl: './view-repairs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-repairs.component.scss']
})
export class ViewRepairsComponent implements OnInit {

  repairs: LogRepair[]=[];

  constructor(private logRepairService: LogRepairService){}
    // Called first time before the ngOnInit()
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Called after the constructor and called after the first ngOnChanges() 

this.repairs = this.logRepairService.getRepairs();

  }
}
```

In the service ts I am exporting a class `LogRepairService` which is an array of hard-coded data of the `LogRepair` type.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LogRepair } from './LogRepair.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogRepairService {

  repairs: LogRepair [] =[
  {name:"Tom",type:"standard",phoneID:"12345",stickerID:"ZX57B",description:"",timestamp: new Date ('2020-02-25T23:18:21.932Z') },
  {name:"Ben",type:"Warranty",phoneID:"54321",stickerID:"B76Gf",description:"touch ic",timestamp: new Date ('2021-02-25T23:18:21.932Z') },
  ];

  constructor() { }

  getRepairs(){
    return this.repairs;
  }

  postRepair(repairs:LogRepair){

  }
}
```

Here is the model ts with the `timestamp` property present.

```
export interface LogRepair
{
   name: string;
   type: string;
   phoneID: string;
   stickerID: string;
   description: string;
   timestamp: Date;
}
```

As the property `timestamp` is present in the interface export, I am struggling to resolve this error.

Comment: Change all these: {{repairs.name}} to repair. (Single, not plural)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the attribute on the array of `LogRepair` that is why the error message includes the square brackets after the type name.

I'm not too familiar with angular but my guess is that you are saying `repairs.timestamp` when you mean to write `repair.timestamp` i.e. the current element in the loop instead of referencing the entire array.

Comment: Thank you, Jason! I changed 'repairs.X' to 'repair.X' and it worked perfectly. I am very new to coding and didn't actually know that one should refer to the name of the element declared in the loop expression. Instead I was trying to reference something altogether different!